# equivalence of definitions of cartier duality

Tags: proof-explanation, sheaf-theory, group-schemes

I am trying to understand the remark on page 20 of [these notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Eserinh/Notes%20on%20p-adic%20Hodge%20theory.pdf).  For $G=\operatorname{Spec} A$ a group scheme, Cartier duality is defined there as $G^\vee(B) = \operatorname{Hom}_{B-grp}(G_B, (\mathbb{G}_m)_B)$.

On the other hand, in the remark it is defined as the sheaf hom $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(G, \mathbb{G}_m)$.  Using this definition, it seems to me that applied to $B$, it would give

$\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(G, \mathbb{G}_m)(B) = \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(G(B), \mathbb{G}_m(B))$,

which does not seem like the same thing.  For instance, if $G=\mathbb{G}_m$, the former appears to be given by $\operatorname{Hom}(B[x, x^{-1}], B[x, x^{-1}])$ while the latter appears to be given by $\operatorname{Hom}(B^\times, B^\times)$.

I am probably overlooking something simple so I'd appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm missing.

Comment: By definition of the sheaf hom: its values on $B$ are what you write as $G^\vee(B)$. Why do you think your 'centered' equation holds true?

Comment: I guess I'm confused about sheaf hom then.  For the fppf site, is it not true that sheaf Hom of (F, G) applied to U is the sheafification of the presheaf sending U to Hom(F(U), G(U)), which is a sheaf?

Comment: No, what you wrote isn't even a presheaf. Given a map $F(U)\to G(U)$ and a map $U'\to U$ how do you get a map $F(U')\to G(U')$?